xskak/chessboard backfields only showing on white squares
Copying and adapting liberally from examples here, I have some working xskak and chessboard code to create a board with custom colors, etc. working properly but for one thing: the highlighting using backfields doesn't show up for dark squares.
For this example, I have highlighted the 2nd rank to demonstrate the problem:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[LSBC5,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}

\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmss}{m}{up}{<->ssub*cmss/m/n}{}

\definecolor{mybrown}{HTML}{974006}
\definecolor{myhighlight}{HTML}{99BB9D}

\storechessboardstyle{mystyle}{
    largeboard,
    boardfontencoding=LSBC5,
    pgfstyle=color,
    color=brown!88,% black fields
    trimtocolor=black,
    backboard,
    trimtocolor=white,
    color=brown!33,% white fields
    backboard,
    whitepiecemaskcolor=white,
    blackpiecemaskcolor=white,
    setfontcolors}

\begin{document}

\setchessboard{
    inverse,
    showmover=true,
    moverstyle=triangle,
    style=mystyle}

\def\myfen{r3r1k1/3nbpp1/pp3n2/3q1PB1/P3N3/8/1PP3BP/R2Q2RK b - - 0 23}

\chessboard[
    addfen=\myfen
    %markstyle=knightmove,
    %color=mybrown,
    %markmoves={d2-e4},
    pgfstyle=color,
    opacity=.5,
    color=myhighlight,
    backfields={h2,g2,f2,e2,d2,c2,b2,a2}
] 

\end{document}

Result:

What I am trying to achieve is something like this (I can't highlight the whole rank, but you can see in the example how the highlight shows on the dark square (d2):

How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

You are trimming the colors to white in your style, and that is still in effect later. Reset the trimming:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[LSBC5,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}

\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmss}{m}{up}{<->ssub*cmss/m/n}{}

\definecolor{mybrown}{HTML}{974006}
\definecolor{myhighlight}{HTML}{99BB9D}

\storechessboardstyle{mystyle}{
    largeboard,
    boardfontencoding=LSBC5,
    pgfstyle=color,
    color=brown!88,% black fields
    trimtocolor=black,
    backboard,
    trimtocolor=white,
    color=brown!33,% white fields
    backboard,
    whitepiecemaskcolor=white,
    blackpiecemaskcolor=white,
    setfontcolors,
    trimtocolor=false} %<------------------

\begin{document}

\setchessboard{
    inverse,
    showmover=true,
    moverstyle=triangle,
    style=mystyle}

\def\myfen{r3r1k1/3nbpp1/pp3n2/3q1PB1/P3N3/8/1PP3BP/R2Q2RK b - - 0 23}

\chessboard[
    addfen=\myfen
    %markstyle=knightmove,
    %color=mybrown,
    %markmoves={d2-e4},
    pgfstyle=color,
    opacity=.5,
    color=myhighlight,
    backfields={h2,g2,f2,e2,d2,c2,b2,a2}
] 

\end{document}



I think backfields should work here, but not even markfields appears to work on black squares. That is, it doesn't work if colouring is chosen. I didn't test the crosses, circles etc. Nor do backrank, markrank, backfile or markfile have any obvious impact on black squares.
I don't know enough about chessboard to say how this is supposed to work, but markranks and markfiles, as well as backranks and backfiles are evidently supposed to work completely differently from markregions and backregions, for instance.
If I reproduce the example from page 55, I get the expected output. If I markrank rather than markfile and change the colour to blue, it also works as expected.
But in your example, it is not just backfields which fails to affect black squares - something which could well be a function of the way things are layered since I imagine the colouring of the square itself may overlay the colour used to mark it - but markfields also has no effect on black squares. So in the code below, I attempt to mark both g5 and g6 with green, but only the white square is affected.
You can work around this by using backregion or backregion, though the effect is not quite the same since the entire square is affected and not just the inner part. So I don't know if this is actually much help.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[LSBC5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}

\storechessboardstyle{mystyle}{
  largeboard,
  boardfontencoding=LSBC5,
  pgfstyle=color,
  color=brown!88,% black fields
  trimtocolor=black,
  backboard,
  trimtocolor=white,
  color=brown!33,% white fields
  backboard,
  whitepiecemaskcolor=white,
  blackpiecemaskcolor=white,
  setfontcolors,
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}%
\newchessgame % from the manual
\setchessboard{tinyboard,
  inverse=false,
  color=orange!80}
\chessboard[boardfontencoding=LSBC5,
  pgfstyle=color,
  trimtocolor=black,
  backboard,
  trimtocolor=white,
  color=gray!50,
  backboard]%
\chessboard[pgfstyle=color,
  padding=-0.2em,
  opacity=0.5,
  markfiles={a,b},
  markregion={e1-h8}]%
\setchessboard{tinyboard,
  color=blue!80,
  clearboard}
\newchessgame
\chessboard[pgfstyle=color,
  padding=-0.2em,
  opacity=0.5,
  markranks={2,3},
  markregion={e1-h8}]%
  
\setchessboard{
  inverse,
  showmover=true,
  moverstyle=triangle,
  style=mystyle,
  color=blue,
}%
\def\myfen{r3r1k1/3nbpp1/pp3n2/3q1PB1/P3N3/8/1PP3BP/R2Q2RK b - - 0 23}%
\chessboard[
    addfen=\myfen
    pgfstyle=color,
    opacity=.5,
    markfile=a,
    markrank=1,
    color=magenta,
    backfile=b,
    backrank=2,
    color=green,
    markfields={f6,g6},
    color=yellow,
    backregion=a5-h5,
    color=red,
    markregion=a7-h7,
] 

\end{document}

Given the package's author, I am not going to say anything about whether this is the intended behaviour or a bug, especially given that transparency is acknowledged to be fragile in the manual and the layering is complex.
I'm afraid I've made something of a monstrosity of your chessboard experimenting with this.

You can see that in the examples from the documentation, the files and ranks are marked as expected, but in the example derived from yours, there is only, for example, one green square rather than two and not even markrank or markfile, which affect the foreground, have any effect on black squares.

Nice colors ;-). I can look later, I'm currently only on my phone.

@UlrikeFischer Aren't they just? Thank you.

My computer died and I am currently getting my new one set up before I can come back to this. I would be grateful for any further insight about these issues, though it looks as though the earlier answer might be enough for my needs. I will check, and mark the answer as accepted as soon as I can actually try it!

@Clorgie You should use Ulrike's answer - not mine.

@UlrikeFischer's answer explains the problem. Not sure what further insight you're asking for exactly?
